# Emacs hold key and press other keys to complete command (while continuing to hold the initial one)

Tags: emacs

Sorry for the weird title but I don't really know how else to describe it. I guess it would be good to use an example. Let's say that I have a bunch of tabs loaded in emacs. If I wanted to cycle through the tabs, I would hold "leader" and then let's say press my arrow keys. After I switched one tab and I wanted to move to the next, I wouldn't have to repress my leader key because it is still being held. Is there any way to do that in emacs?

P.S: I am looking for something similar to byobu. For example: holding shift and using arrow keys to move around panes

Comment: Sounds like the kind of thing `ido-mode` does.

Comment: Emacs is also somewhat at the mercy of the OS. It does a lot to bypass the OS but if the hardware keyboard chords are not exposed somehow, there is no way for Emacs to do what you describe.

Comment: I guess it also depends on what you mean by "leader key". I'm guessing you mean a prefix key like `C-x`, not a modifier key like Alt?

Comment: @tripleee I use Arch Linux and doom emacs. I don't think it should be a problem because I do it all the time in byobu. Byobu is probably the main reason I want something like this because it just make hotkeys so much quicker

Comment: If it's about pressing and holding pressed then you're talking about a *modifier* key, such as `Meta`, `Shift`, or `Control`. If it's instead about hitting a key and then repeatedly hitting another key (same other key), then that's about `repeat` or similar (e.g. transient keymap).

Comment: The next guess will be mine: is the question about navigating the **tabs** specifically? For navigation between **windows**, take a look at the `windmove` built-in package. Or `repeat-mode` indeed starting Emacs 28.1 for anything that requires a command's "trailing part" repetitive hitting.

Comment: If you want to use arbitrary keys as modifiers (for example F keys or alphanumerics), be aware your keyboard probably physically doesn't support it - .You'll need an expensive mechanical keyboard with a feature they call "true anti ghosting", or something. Even most "anti-ghosting" keyboards only allow common key combos used in games (e.g. space + WASD keys).